# Import django pluggable apps from project subdirectory

Tags: python, django, importerror, python-import, django-apps

I have some Django project sturcture:

```
PROJECT
--APPS
----Profile
----...
--PLUGINS
----ENDLESS_PAGINATION
----DJANGO_SUBDOMAINS
----...
```

And for example: in ENDLESS_PAGINATION models.py file is import:

```
from endless_pagination import ...
```

which can't be done.

> ImportError: No module named endless_pagination

It only works when I have this structure:

```
PROJECT
--DJANGO_SUBDOMAINS
--ENDLESS_PAGINATION
--APPS
----Profile
----...
```

But I prefer the first and don't like change my plugins imports. Please help!

Comment: Are these plugins in third party apps?

Comment: All Django apps would be on the same level so by default there's no distinction between external Django apps and your own.

Comment: yes James, MIT licenese

Comment: ok Simon. I will chcange much these plugins - and will be like part of my job. So I will use them like others my apps.
We can close the question and thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the PLUGINS directory in your PYTHONPATH.

In your settings.py add:

## settings.py

```
import os, sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'APPS'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'PLUGINS'))
```

After that, you can refer to modules in apps or plugins without need "apps." or "plugins." prefix.

The PROJECT_ROOT layout is for django 1.4 or newest, if you are using django 1.3 or lowest you will probably do this `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`.